# ASP.NET Core project cannot find class/method in its referenced project

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core

as a beginner I tried to follow right way to create a class library project or ASP.Net core webApi. The situation of mine is:

1) I created a class library project (let's call it 'AAA') using .net Core. The framework for a class library should be "**netstandard1.6**" I know. I defined 1 static class and its methods.

2) Then I create another Asp.Net Core WebApi project, and let's call it 'BBB' The default framework in project.json file is "**netcoreapp1.0**" then.

Then in project BBB -- 'References' I add project AAA as reference. No error happens. However if I try to use the static class/method defined in prject AAA, Visual studio told me that static class could not be found. (Instead of traditional .Net project it will auto-pop suggestion and if I click the link, VS automatically add code and sort it out for me.)

But if I move mouse on top of the red error part, VS (or re-sharper) did suggest like "Reference prject AAA... NETStandard, Version=v1.6' and use project AAA.static class/method....". However even if I click on the suggestion, there is still NO changes at all.

How come for that and how could I fix it?

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Have you tried adding both netcoreapp1.0 and netstandard1.6 yo your AAA project? https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cesardelatorre/2016/06/28/running-net-core-apps-on-multiple-frameworks-and-what-the-target-framework-monikers-tfms-are-about/

Comment: Can you put some code in your question ? Like the both project.json and your static class.

Comment: Mitch, I added both netcoreapp1.0 and netstandard1.6 into json file of class library project and it's the same.

Comment: Adrien, my 2 project.json files are the same as what you posted below. Actually for the dependency in ASP webApi project, as long as you add the class library as reference, the project.json file seems will get updated automatically?

Answer (score 0):

The .NET Standard library framework is used by the .NET Core class library, but not by your .NET Core application.

So your class library has a project.json like this :

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",

  "dependencies": {
    "NETStandard.Library": "1.6.0"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netstandard1.6": {
      "imports": "dnxcore50"
    }
  }
}
```

And to reference this class library into a .NET Core application, you have to add the depencency, with the default imports and it will work :

```
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "version": "1.0.1",
      "type": "platform"
    },
    "Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.0.0",
    "ClassLibrary1": "1.0.0-*"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.6",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },
```

With this both project.json files, the reference is great and if I add a static class in my class library like :

```
public static class Class2
{
    public static void Test()
    {

    }
}
```

I can call this method in a web app controller, like :

```
[HttpGet]
public void TestStaticCall()
{
    ClassLibrary1.Class2.Test();
}
```

Comment: My class library project Json file and WebAPI project json are exactly the same as your post. But still could not find that static class (or namespace) in main webapi class.

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved this from this post: https://github.com/aspnet/Tooling/issues/664. Update Resharper did help! Thanks a lot every one!!